# Check if a function is concave, convex or neither of these

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I need to find out if the following equation is concave, convex, or neither and am unsure how to do so.

$$f(x,y) = −3x^2 − 4y^2\quad\forall x, y \in \mathbb R$$

So the first step is to replace $y$ with $x$ and take two derivatives, right?
$$\begin{align}
&g(x) = -7x^2\\
&g'(x) = -14x\\
&g''(x) = -14
\end{align}$$

Was that right?

Answer (score 0):

No, that just tells you about concave/convex for the restrictions to the line $y=x$.

Hint: the sum of two concave/convex functions is concave/convex.

Comment: okay so then take the 2nd derivative replacing x with y?